# Google drive file upload with service account and PHP

Tags: php, upload, drive

I have bee looking for a way for my web app users be able to upload files but avoid filling the limited hosting space I have. Google drive sounded like a perfect fit but now i'm stuck at how to use PHP for uploading files to my gdrive using a service account. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Was able to upload files using oAuth but I don't want my web app users to upload their files on their own Drive but mine. I think using the service account is the right road to go but i'm still scratching my head on to go about using it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP upload a file on google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867880/php-upload-a-file-on-google-drive)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think this uses oAuth but what I want to do is through a service account. Appreciate this and I will try this one too.

Comment: @IvoMori Thanks a lot will do. This is my first time posting a question on this platform though I've been getting valuable information from here for many years.